# How do I loop multiple conditions in different statements, and make it loop If the conditions are not met?

Tags: python

I need help specifically with my piece of code. It does not seem to output what I want. If I try to while loop it, and the value is wrong, it still continues. Lots of errors here and I'm not sure how to repair.

```
weapon_2 = "axe"
weapon_3 = "spiked club"

weapon_1 = weapon_1.strip().lower()
weapon_2 = weapon_1.strip().lower()
weapon_3 = weapon_1.strip().lower()

weapon = input ("Please select a weapon: Sword, Axe, Spiked Club.\n")
weapon = weapon.strip().lower()



if weapon == weapon_1:
    print("Nice choice! I would pick {} too!".format(weapon))
    
elif weapon == weapon_2:
    print("Nice choice! I would pick {} too!".format(weapon))
    
elif weapon == weapon_3:
    print("Nice choice! I would pick {} too!".format(weapon))

while weapon != (weapon_1) or (weapon_2) or (weapon_3):
    print("Invalid option.")
    weapon = input ("Please select a weapon: Sword, Axe, Spiked Club.\n")
```

Comment: Hint: Use a data storing method where you pass the value once and check if it is present there or not.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

`while weapon != (weapon_1) or (weapon_2) or (weapon_3):`

With:

`while weapon not in (weapon_1, weapon_2, weapon_3):`

`or` is evaluating `(weapon_2)` as a boolean, it sees a `str` so evaluates as `True` and the `while` loop continues running.

You should also make the options in your print statement textually identical to the options, otherwise the user will type "Axe", which does not match "axe" and be told it's an invalid option.

Comment: Good catch, but the real problem lies in a variable assignment error. weapon_2 and weapon_3 are assigned to be stripped lowercases of weapon_1, instead of weapon_2 and weapon_3 respectively. Just a copy paste error

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be some refinement for the while loop to keep "looping"

```
weapon_1, weapon_2, weapon_3  = "sword", "axe", "spiked club"

while True:
    weapon = input("Please select a weapon: Sword, Axe, Spiked Club.\n").strip().lower()
    
    if weapon == weapon_1:
        print(f"Nice choice! I would pick {weapon_1} too!")
    elif weapon == weapon_2:
        print(f"Nice choice! I would pick {weapon_2} too!")
    elif weapon == weapon_3:
        print(f"Nice choice! I would pick {weapon_3} too!")
    elif weapon == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weapons = ["sword", "axe", "spiked club"]

while True:

    # input
    user_input = input("Please select a weapon: Sword, Axe, Spiked Club. ('stop' to exit)\n")
    user_input_lower = user_input.strip().lower()
    if user_input_lower == 'stop':
        break

    # weapon precessing
    weapon = user_input_lower
    if weapon in weapons:
        print(f"Nice choice! I would pick {user_input} too!")
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```